# JAWS reads Headings as clickable even though parent div has not click handler associated

Tags: html, angular, testing, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader

I am working on accessibility testing for an Angular project. I have some code for a modal that is as below

```html
<div class="modal fade" bsModal #cancelConfirmModal="bs-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
    attr.aria-label="Cancel Modal" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="md-dialog modal-md">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="md-content">
            <div class="md-header">
                <div class="md-title pull-left">
                    <h4 tabindex=0 class="headerBottomMarginNone"> Cancel</h4>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="close-popup" (click)="hideCancelModal()">
                    <img src="{{ pathImg }}/close.png" alt="Close Icon"
                        (mouseover)="changeCloseIconOnHover('close-popup3')"
                        (mouseout)="changeCloseIcon('close-popup3')" id="close-popup3">
                    <label class="sr-only">Close</label>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div tabindex=0 class="md-body">
                {{ cancelMessageBody }}
            </div>
            <div class="md-footer">
                <button type="reset pull-right" class="ts-btn ts-btn-primary no-btm-margin" (click)="revert()">Yes</button>
                <button type="pull-right" (click)="hideCancelModal()"
                    class="ts-btn ts-btn-tertiary margin-left10 no-btm-margin">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I tab over to `<h4 tabindex=0 class="headerBottomMarginNone"> Cancel</h4>` it reads **Cancel heading level 4 clickable**. There is no click event on the parent or even its parent. h4 is made tab reachable as per the QA's preference. How do I stop JAWS from announcing clickable??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short Answer

Remove the `tabindex`.

### Long Answer

Headings should not have a `tabindex` (other than maybe a `tabindex="-1"`, covered below).

Anything with a `tabindex` is considered to be interactive and it is expected that you have supplied the relevant handlers for focus, click, keyboard keys etc.

Your QA is incorrect on this and is making the software harder to use.

The only time it is appropriate to use a `tabindex` on a heading is if you need to programatically focus it (for example on an AJAX application where you load a new page in it is a good practice to focus the heading level 1 on the page to let screen reader users know the new page has loaded in.) At this point the only `tabindex` that is appropriate is `tabindex="-1"` so that it can only be focused programatically and not via the <kbd>tab</kbd> key.

Your QA may think that screen reader users need to be able to focus the headings, this is not the case! They use shortcut keys within their screen reader to access headings on the page.

Also remove it from `<div tabindex=0 class="md-body">` as that is also not interactive.

Finally it is likely you do not need `tabindex="-1"` on the modal itself as when you open the modal you should focus either the first interactive element or the close button (which in your case appears to be the cancel button anyway.), however there may be functionality in your software that I am not aware of so that is just a point to consider.

Comment: Hmmm. QA usually don't check the code when doing accessibility testing. And such things always come up wherein they want JAWS to behave a certain way, but we can't make that happen due to the code we have, in this case the <h4> tag. We could probably cheat and use a span with appropriate css instead of a heading tag but that would be even worse I guess.

Comment: What is your QA using for accessibility testing? I think they have misunderstood what people who use a keyboard as a primary input need. Screen magnifier users just need to access all interactive elements and screen reader users can get to everything else through shortcuts in their screen reader. I would imagine they have misunderstood accessibility requirements. https://webaim.org/resources/shortcuts/jaws#headings perhaps this page would be useful to them so they know how screen readers are used (or at least the controls that are used). Hope that helps.

Comment: Not sure to be honest. Devs code with fuctionality in mind, and most of the keyboard shortcuts seem to support that. Even if we don't use html elements for certain things (eg making table out of divs) generally enough care is taken so that the using aria tags. The link is very helpful. I'll bring it up with QA.